# Collapse if-else statement with assignment

Tags: if-statement, kotlin

I am trying to do a null/empty check-in a conditional block as seen below:

[image]

However, the results are kind of bizzare in that the block with `!filter.isNullOrEmpty()`  should not execute since the filter is null. How does `isNullOrEmpty()` usually work, and how and when to use it?

I just have a simple set up like:

```java
val filter : String? = session.parameters["filter"]?.get(0).toString()

            val rootJsonObject = JsonObject()
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()

            val list  = if (!filter.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                NetApp.database.filmDao().getByRegionFilter(filter)
            } else {
                NetApp.database.filmDao().getByRandom()
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `filter` contains the string `"null"`, but it's not actually null or empty. If it was null, it'd look like `filter = null` in the variables section, not `filter = "null"`, note the quotes.

The reason `filter` contains the string `"null`" is that you call `toString()` on `session.parameters["filter"]?.get(0)` not in a null-safe way. `get(0)` returns a `null` value and `null.toString()` returns the literal string `"null"`. To fix that, simply make it a null-safe call: `session.parameters["filter"]?.get(0)?.toString()`

Comment: quotes, not parentheses (those are `(` and `)`)